# how to get azure repos details into csv file using api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

hi team I want PowerShell script for to get azure repos details like (name of repo, no. of branches, PR approvers for branches, policy for branches) converted into csv file using azure API.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What have you attempted? What documentation have you checked? Are you having any specific issues implementing a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$OrgName = "xxx"
$ProjectName = "xxx"
$RepoName = "xxx"
$PAT = "xxx"

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)

$response = Invoke-RestMethod ("https://dev.azure.com/"+$OrgName+"/"+$ProjectName+"/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1") -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers #Get repos
$response | ConvertTo-Json

foreach ($ele in $response.value) {
    if($ele.name -eq $RepoName){
        $headers2 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        $headers2.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)

        $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://dev.azure.com/'+$OrgName+'/'+$ProjectName+'/_apis/git/repositories/'+$ele.id+'/refs?api-version=6.0') -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers #Get refs
        $response2 | ConvertTo-Json

        $count = 0

        foreach ($ele2 in $response2.value) {
            if($ele2.name.contains("refs/heads/")){
                $count = $count + 1
            }
        }
        #===
        $headers3 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        $headers3.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)

        $response3 = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://dev.azure.com/'+$OrgName+'/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4') -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers #Get projects
        $response3 | ConvertTo-Json
        $ele3_1
        foreach ($ele3 in $response3.value) {
            if($ele3.name -eq $ProjectName){
                Write-Host "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"+$ele3.id #Get the project id
                Write-Host $ele3.id #Get the project id
                $ele3_1 = $ele3.id
            }
        }
        #===
        $headers4 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        $headers4.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)

        $response4 = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://dev.azure.com/'+$OrgName+'/'+$ele3_1+'/_apis/policy/Configurations') -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers #Get Project policy configurations
        $response4 | ConvertTo-Json

        $reviewers= @()
        foreach ($ele4 in $response4.value) {
            $ele4 | ConvertTo-Json
            if(($ele4.settings.requiredReviewerIds -ne $null) -and ($ele4.settings.scope.repositoryId -eq $ele.id)){
                #Write-Host $ele4.settings.requiredReviewerIds #Get reviewers id of specific branch.
                $reviewers += $ele4.settings.requiredReviewerIds
                $count4++
            }
        }
        Write-Host $ele.id #Get the repo id.
        Write-Host $count #Get the number of branches of specific repo.
        Write-host $reviewers #Get the reviewers.
        # Write-Host $ele3_1
        # Write-Host "xxx"
        $object = [pscustomobject]@{Repo=$ele.id;NumberOfbranches=$count;Reviewers=[string]$reviewers}

        $object | Select-Object Repo,NumberOfbranches,Reviewers | Export-Csv -Path .\WmiData.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]